# На удаленном вопросе ломается верстка

Tags: дефект, статус-воспроизведено, дизайн

Похоже, переведенная строка длиннее, чем оригинал. Поэтому она наезжает на блок с последним редактором сообщения.

Firefox 39.0, OS X 10.10

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/174810/

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

обновление 2015-08-26: браузер *iceweasel* (aka *firefox*) разных версий. никаких изменений за последние месяцы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните, какой обозреватель вы используете. У меня проблема [не воспроизводится](http://i.stack.imgur.com/jOkBT.png). Обозреватель Google Chrome 44 (64-bit).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: обновил

Comment: Действительно, под Firefox разметка сломана. Добавил в базу дефектов. Спасибо!

Comment: Подтверждаю, снова сломалось.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, а я, пользуясь *iceweasel*-ом, так ни разу не заметил ни одной «починки».